# Plotting phase portrait for second order ODE(which has no analytical solution)

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm trying to plot $ y(t) $ against $ y'(t) $ (phase portrait) for the following ODE:

$$ y''(t) + y(t)+9.8*sgn(y'(t))=0  $$

where all derivatives are with respect to $t$. Due to the presence of the signum function, this ODE has no closed form solution(as far as I know). So, is there a way to plot something like this in Mathematica without getting an explicit solution? All the tutorials for StreamPlot, ParametricPlot, and other similar things that I have seen involve equations which are a lot more "tamer" in some sense.  Hence, something like the following lines of code seem to not work:

```
ode = y''[t] == - y[t]-9.8*Sign[y'[t]]


ic = {y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1}
sol = y[t] /. First@(DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[t], t])
ParametricPlot[{Evaluate[sol, 
 D[sol, t]]}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Maybe `Clear[ode, ic, sol];
ode = y''[t] == -y[t] - 9.8*Sign[y'[t]];
ic = {y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1};
sol = First@(NDSolve[{ode, ic}, y, {t, 0, 10}]);
ParametricPlot[{y[t], y'[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]`

Comment: @cvgmt Thank you. That seems to have done it.